# facebook canvas is not available

Tags: facebook, canvas, facebook-canvas

My app url is http://example.com/nomi/index.php.

I want to show it in facebook canvas. Below is the setup.

```
App Namespace: awardapp
App Domain: example.com
Site URL: http://example.com/nomi
Canvas URL: http://example.com/nomi/
Secure Canvas URL: https://example.com/nomi/
Canvas Page: http://apps.facebook.com/awardapp
```

I tried many times but the page is always not available. I believe it's the configuration problem because http://example.com/nomi works fine when I type it in the browser.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something went wrong, when you created this app, because this namespace (awardapp) is still available.

Comment: Thanks. Actually awardapp is not the real name for my project. I just want to show that the canvas page name is configured correctly.

Comment: It's the problem! The error on https page is the same with the facebook canvas page. Do you know how to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: In this case it is a server issue. I suppose something wrong with you SSL cert. Try to contact with your server hosting company to solve that. If you haven't got SSL cert, you have to buy one. I you wouldn't like to buy, you can use Heroku http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/facebook

Comment: Thank you very much. It's really a great help. One more question: my app is running on ixwebhosting and I didn't buy SSL cert. Can I use Heroku in this situation? SSL and hosting can be provided by different companies?

Comment: Heroku could help I think, just read the article what I linked. SSL:I'm not sure, but I think so. I try to get everything from one company, in this case you exactly know who is involved. ;)